# How is this string being formatted in python

Tags: python, string, format

I am going through a tutorial for a python library. Found this example code :

```
>>> device = monitor.poll(timeout=3)
>>> if device:
...     print('{0.action}: {0}'.format(device))
...
```

I know the meaning of {0} and in this `.format()` template. What does `{0.action}` mean and how does it get processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instructive example:

```
>>> class Device:
    def __init__(self):
        self.action = "bar"
    def __str__(self):
        return "foo"


>>> device = Device()
>>> print('{0.action}: {0}'.format(device))
bar: foo
```

The "dot notation" `instance.attribute` can be used to access attributes in `str.format` just as it can elsewhere.

Comment: oh! simple and clean. 9 minutes until I can accept an answer so must wait.